Why don't words like "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday" etc. have the adverb denotation in their dictionary definitions?
I had always thought of and treated them as nouns when they were used as time descriptions for specific actions therefore in my usage they had always followed after a preposition in cases like [Subject] Do [action] on [X]day (I read a book on Monday).
However, I recently noticed in many news articles those "day words" are used without the preposition under similar use cases i.e. they are treated as adverbs (I read a book Monday). After some digging around, it appears to be an American English phenomenon (reference). I tried looking up some front page articles on BBC and CNN/FOX/USA TODAY as a source to compare between British and American English while BBC uses "on [X]day" all the time, the American outlets use just "[X]day" in their writings almost exclusively in the handful of articles I sifted through.
Even though its usage seems extremely prevalent in AE, in none of the major free dictionaries I have done my research in(other than Wiktionary, I have been told OED also mentions it, but I do not have subscription access to it) including Merriam-Webster, which is an American dictionary, mentioned those words' adverbial usage.
Is it because this is a relatively recent phenomenon in the American English and an example of the language "evolving" and the dictionaries not being kept up to date with the words newly adopted common usage?
My understanding of the function of dictionaries is they are to reflect the accepted formal usage of words based on the statistical consensus of the demographics speaking that language, it's a form of endorsement so whether or not the use of a word is formally correct when appealing to a specific dictionary one can simply look into the word's entry in that dictionary if the definition applied that's in question is there.
P.S., I'm not wondering about the inner workings of dictionaries like Webster (also Collins, Cambridge and Dictionary.com are the sources I can find that do not have those words as adverbs in definitions) per se, I'm wondering based on their good reputations at collecting how people use words aka authority, however they worked to achieve that, their content is made with a presumably deliberate intent rather than a mistake. And they might not be updated maybe only because the usage is more recent, even though a significant number of the population accepts that usage.

Hard to tell whether you mean you read a book last Monday, or you do read a book every Monday.  (Mondaily?)

@komodosp It seems to be just an equivalent to "on Monday" and is different from "every Monday/on Mondays/Mondays". So in the context of I read a book on Monday, it's most likely the Monday this week being referred to from a future date under the same week.

This question is similar to: What is the function of "Monday?". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. // As it stands, the question is not suitable for ELU (the inner workings of dictionary usage panels is subjective), and erroneous (OED includes the 'adverb' classification); the root question is 'What is the POS of 'Monday' in "We'll see you Monday."

@EdwinAshworth Thx for the link to the post which would have been an answer to my question originally, however now my confusion is even deeper combined with the others responses below. Wouldn't the answer to that accepted post be in direct contradiction(that it's a noun not an adv) to the OED/Wiktionary definition that it is an adv in that use? Also I apologize to jumping to conclusions, I do not have a premium subscription to OED and couldn't access it, I should have clarified that my conclusion was based only on my own limited dictionary research.

With regard to your PS, not necessarily. Dictionaries can simply record usage (and so by recording that something is used, it can become "correct"). OED is a historical dictionary and records usage over time. I'm not convinced that @Edwin is correct in asserting that OED's adverb classification is wrong, given the Old English example. It does appear to me that the question has become rambling and indistinct with your edits. If you need to clarify a question (without fundamentally changing it), just alter it to clarify.

@AndrewLeach That's what I was trying to say in my PS, that dictionaries are there to record the usage of a word if the usage has been observed from a significant number of people, as a form of endorsement or acknowledgement of that usage. So by not endorsing that usage are those dictionaries saying they haven't observed that usage because it's something recent or some responses seem to say that the adverbial Monday is still considered a noun, does that contradict OED? The possibility I left out is they are unintentionally mistaken in not recording that usage otherwise would have if they knew

@AndrewLeach My Question still remains "Why don't words like "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday" etc. have the adverb denotation in their dictionary definitions?" Which seems to be distinct from the duplicate post Edwin Ashworth linked up "What is the function of "Monday?" in that my post is presupposing the function of "Monday" to be adverbial and asking why then is adverb not considered one of its classes under lexical authorities like these dictionaries. The presupposition might be wrong if it still remains noun in the adverbial usage, but that appears to be in contention.

If that's your question, then we can't answer for dictionaries' policy. We can say "OED [at least] says it's an adverb in that usage," but we can't say why MW doesn't say that.

@AndrewLeach So would you agree with the verdict that, if those dictionaries definitions weren't unintentionally left out, then for the sentence I read a book Monday, Monday there is grammatically correctly applied according to OED and the dictionaries that agree with the definition, while is incorrectly/inappropriately/informally applied according to MW and the dictionaries that disagree with the definition.

@Andrew My assertion was that OP's 'Even though its usage seems extremely prevalent in AE, in (sic) none of the major dictionaries (other than Wiktionary) including the Merriam Webster which I thought was the authoritative dictionary for AE, mentioned those words' adverbial usage.' was erroneous. 6/7 edits back.

@GothomWR No, your verdict is faulty. But here in comments is no place to discuss this matter further.

OED does have [eg] Monday listed as an adverb:

adverb

On Monday; last Monday; next Monday. Now chiefly North American.


But its citations start with Old English

Habbe we us gerædd..þæt we ælcere wucan singan ii mæssan on ælcum mynstre, synderlice for eallum gebroðrum, monandæge, & frigedæge.

Agreement of Confraternity with Other Houses, Bath (Corpus Christi Cambridge MS. 111) in W. Hunt, Two Chartularies Priory St. Peter at Bath (1893) 4


...and the last British citation which is listed for the adverbial use is dated 1853 [apart from an entry in the Good Pub Guide, which is abbreviated  journalese anyway].
So it appears that this use has died out in BrE while it's alive and strong in AmE. It's not actually a recent phenomenon at all.
I have no explanation for American dictionaries' not including it as an adverb. Perhaps they classify this usage differently.

I did read that the adverbial usage is used rarely and mostly as informal speech in BrE, I don't know if the AmE usage was still from the same historical usage continuation, like I'm not sure if they mostly stopped using it in NA like the UK and then only recently went back to the old way to make their speech more compact and easy.
By "classifying the usage differently" do you mean those dictionaries perhaps  don't call that usage as adverbial? On Webster for example "Monday"'s only definition is the "noun., the second day of the week".

Do AmE dictionaries have example sentences? I would find it difficult to class "I'll do it Monday" as merely a noun, but perhaps they do, saying that the omission of the preposition does not change its class. All my answer says is that it's a usage which would have gone across the Atlantic with the Mayflower and has apparently diverged since.

They do have example sentences on Webster, still take "Monday" as example, the first few examples are simple and what I suspect to be artificially created/selected sentences like "I'll arrive on Monday", and I suppose they will stay there. Right below that section are the web auto-collected sentences from news sites(not sure if all of them are NA based), they are more concurrent I guess they are constantly updated. One of their examples right now there is: "The matter is on the agenda for discussion at the School Board's meeting Monday."
— Al Gaspeny, Arkansas Online, 16 July 2023

Isn't "omission" more of a phenomenon of informal speech and writings? The places I found these examples in like their major news reportings I would expect them not to omit words unless quoting someone, and if it's in the formal writing then that just seems to me to mean the writer's intention is to use a word like Monday as an adverb. Which I thought was a basic grammatical mistake until I saw their frequent usage in various serious settings.

@GothomWR No, we've always been able to use certain kinds of noun phrases, specifically "temporal" or "locative" ones, as adverbial adjuncts without a connective preposition in English: “I’ll clean out the shed next week when I have more time. Wait here (for) just a minute and I’ll get right back to you. Unlike their predators, antelope can run (for) miles and miles without needing a rest. I quite liked how their tree was trimmed last Christmas. Here we open our presents (on) Christmas Day.”

@tchrist Thx for the examples, I had to look up noun phrases, Wikipedia says "A noun phrase[...] is a phrase that [...] has the same grammatical functions as a noun", if I'm understanding this correctly, those phrases  wouldn't they be disqualified from being "noun phrases" in those examples since grammatically they functioned like adverbs? And they would only be noun phrases where they function as nouns such as "I have one last week and you have just a minute", and if they had entries in a dictionary I'd expect it categorically to reflect both their noun and adverb properties.

In the Old English example the word dæg  has an -e case ending marking it as adverbial.

Dictionaries tend not to give detailed definitions of proper nouns, if you look at how Merriam-Webster defines Monday, January, etc - it says what it is in a brief definition but doesn't go into the full details of what people do on Mondays, what the connotations are, etc. You could use Monday as an adjective or a verb, and readers consulting dictionaries (especially general-purpose dictionaries) are expected to have some basic knowledge of how the English language works. Similarly, dictionaries sometimes indicate if a noun can be used attributively but they don't do it for every noun.

@GothomWR Your mental model is missing an entire level of analysis: category ≠ function. When you only think in terms of a word’s category, its  “part of speech”, you can't do any higher level syntactic analysis because a POS only applies to a single word, never to a phrase’s or clause’s function as a syntactic constituent. The key concept you're missing is “grammatical role”, which are things like subject, object, complement, predicate, modifier, adjunct, supplement. These are the syntactic functions that govern an individual constituent’s role within the surrounding elements.

@tchrist Thx for the criticism, my understanding is a category presupposes possible functions, so a statement like "the word functions like a noun" makes sense because it implies the noun category permits specific possible functions which can be examined. Now maybe my confusion about the academic dogma is whether the category of a word is informed or even determined by the word's applied functions, for example "I shoe my sneakers" would be a mistake because shoe isn't a verb but if for whatever reason many people start saying it I'd imagine it'd then be accepted as truth that shoe is a verb

@StuartF That's a great point and my blind spot. I'm only speculating but is it a caveat when certain uses are universal, for example if all nouns can be used attributively(and "verbially"?) then it might be trivial to add an adjective definition to all noun word entries and more convenient to create a rule to point out that universality, and only when a word's adjectival usage is statistically significant, sometimes surpasses its original usage did it become worth noting. I'm not sure there is such universality so as to make pointing it out trivial for a dictionary in using a noun adverbially

The main reason that this should be the case is that there's a difference between a word's category and its syntactic function. The word Monday is still a noun in:

I'll see you Monday.

just like it is in:

I'll see you this Monday.

or even in:

I'll see you on Monday.

In the first example, the noun Monday is functioning as an Adjunct (read 'Adverbial'), in the second it is functioning s the Head of the noun phrase this Monday and in the third it is functioning as Complement of the preposition on. However, in each case it is still, of course, a noun (and not an adverb!).

Thx for the answer, this is similar to Tchrist's response under leach's answer so I have the same 2 question, 1) does a word's category not signify its permissible functions/properties and henceforth you can backward deduce its possible categories from the applied functions/properties. For instance, if a verb may not have the function of modifier, then a word serving the function of modifier is not considered possible to be a verb. Or is the claim all syntactic functions can be possibly served by some elements of all categories(or is it only in the case of nouns serving as adverbials) and...

2)"A noun phrase – or NP or nominal (phrase) – is a phrase that usually has a noun or pronoun as its head, AND has the same grammatical functions as a noun" from Wikipedia. Whether the head Monday is a noun is in question, but doesn't the second part of that NP definition suggest a phrase grammatically functioning non-nominally but adverbially disqualifies from being a "noun phrase"?

@GothomWR 1) does a word's category not signify its permissible functions/properties and henceforth you can backward deduce its possible categories from the applied functions/properties. This is rarely possible because most types of word or phrase can have several different types of function and most functions can be carried out by several types of word or phase. For example, as in this case, the function of temporal Adjunct within a clause can be carried out by preposition phrases, noun phrases and adverb phrases. So we cannot simply decide that a temporal adjunct must be an adverb!

@GothomWR [D]oesn't the second part of that NP definition suggest a phrase grammatically functioning non-nominally but adverbially disqualifies from being a "noun phrase"? [Setting aside the wisdom of trying to get reliable grammatical info from Wikipedia ...] No, because such a description of course expressly allows for NPs to function as temporal adjuncts precisely because nouns (i.e. 1-word NPs) can function as temporal adjuncts. We cannot align syntactic functions with a particular type of word or phrase because that would just conflate the word category and syntactic function!

@GothomWR And the first principle of the best modern grammars is to avoid such confused analysis by keeping word and phrase categories, syntactic functions (aka grammatical relations), and meanings separate [Btw, just for clarification, verbs can of course function as modifiers!]

Thx for the detailed replies. 2 final questions, 1) I thought nouns like Monday even though they can serve like adjectives(Monday night) the reason they aren't listed as such in dictionary entries is because nouns being used attributively is a universal phenomenon so it's trivial to list out each noun's adjective sense but rather more convenient to make it a property of nouns, is this true and if so is nouns being used adverbially a similar universal phenomenon of the noun category like noun attributivity and...

2)OED, as Leach has pointed out in his answer(to which I have no membership access to), and Wiktionary on the word Monday have listed out the the usage of I'll see you Monday as using its adverb sense(==on Monday) doesn't the adverb claim by these 2 dictionaries contradict that the claim that it isn't an adverb(the noun (Monday is) functioning as an Adjunct((read) 'Adverbial')) or would you say these 2 dictionaries are claiming (the noun (Monday is) functioning as an Adjunct((read) 'Adverbial')) is the equivalent of being an adverb

@GothomWR Will pop back and finish discussion of get the time. For now, I think this might answer some of your questions Why not to consult dictionaries for grammatical information!

@GothomWR You should not say that Monday "acts like an adjective" in the phrase Monday night. It’s instead a modifier used attributively before the thing modified. You have to look at syntactic functions not at word category. In particular actual per-se adjectives have many, many other syntactic properties than this alone. As one small example we might otherwise be tempted to pretend that words such as the and an were adjectives, and we should absolutely not do that.
